# Ajax Error Potentially Due to Incorrect Data Object Being Passed

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Hi I am new to ajax and I am attempting to pass a Json to a Database, but I am not that far yet. Currently I am attempting to be verified that the data I am passing is being done successfully. However, I always drop into the ajax error method. I will upload my code and the way the data looks and then the error.

Thank you for your help!

```
<script>
function updateTable()
{
    alert("Do i try to update table?");
    document.getElementById("testLand").innerHTML = "Post Json";
    //echo new table values for ID = x
}
function popupClick (){
    var popupObj = {};
    popupObj["Verified_By"] = $('#popupVBy').val();
    popupObj["Date_Verified"] = $('#popupDV').val();
    popupObj["Comments"] = $('#popupC').val();
    popupObj["Notes"] = $('#popupN').val();
    var popupString = JSON.stringify(popupObj);
    alert(popupString);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "popupAjax.php",
        data: popupObj,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) 
        {
            alert("Success");
            updateTable();
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
            alert("there was an error in the ajax");
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));

        }
    });
}
</script>
```

JSON Being Passed shown in var popupString:

[image: JSON Being Passed shown in popupString]

Error:

[image]

popupAjax.php file (warning it's testy)

```
<?php
echo "Testing tests are testy";
?>
```

Comment: What's the server side code that processes this request?

Comment: I will add it 1 sec.

Comment: The line `dataType: "json",` says your response will be json but your response is not json which causes the error you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying the `dataType` as json. But this is the returned data type, not the type of the data you are sending.

You are returning html / text so you can just remove the `dataType` line:

```
    type: "POST",
    url: "popupAjax.php",
```

If you do want to return json, you need to build your datastructure on the server-side and send it at the end. In your test-case it would just be:

```
echo json_encode("Testing tests are testy");
```

But you could send a nested object or array as well.

As an additional note, you can use `.serialize()` on your form (if you use a form...) so that jQuery automatically builds an object that you can send in the ajax method. Then you don't have to do that manually.

Comment: Thanks for the help jeroen, I removed dataType: "json", but I am still dropping into my error function, do you know why that is?

Comment: @vector I just added a note about `.serialize()`. Perhaps the data structure  you are sending is wrong and causes an error although it doesn't look like it. You can also check the console for the exact response, that might give some clues.

Comment: I am not using a form, I am actually just grabbing variables, but where would I add the .serialize() if I was using a form?

Comment: @vector That would be something like `data: $('form').serialize(),`. What do you see in the console, what is the exact response?

Comment: This actually, wasn't a complete solution but it provided some very helpful information. The problem was actually in a different part of my code that didn't really have anything to do with the ajax. But telling me about the form took me too the issue. Thanks for all the help!